# Reasons For Akka Actor being terminated

Tags: akka, actor

I am trying to debug an issue where my actor is being terminated somehow .

What are the reasons for an actor to get terminated? it is not getting restarted again.

how can i debug it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following config to log all events occuring in your actor system

```
akka {

  debug {
      # enable function of Actor.loggable(), which is to log any received message
      # at DEBUG level, see the “Testing Actor Systems” section of the Akka
      # Documentation at http://akka.io/docs
      receive = on

      # enable DEBUG logging of all AutoReceiveMessages (Kill, PoisonPill et.c.)
      autoreceive = on

      # enable DEBUG logging of actor lifecycle changes
      lifecycle = on

      # enable DEBUG logging of all LoggingFSMs for events, transitions and timers
      fsm = on

      # enable DEBUG logging of subscription changes on the eventStream
      event-stream = on

      # enable DEBUG logging of unhandled messages
      unhandled = on

      # enable WARN logging of misconfigured routers
      router-misconfiguration = on
    }

}
```

Read [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html) if you don't know where to place the config.

When the actor is not restarted, you need to define a supervision strategy in your parent actor, see [Supervision and Monitoring](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html)